# erros in eclipse C++ by opening file from ros tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all,

when i open the add_two_ints_server.cpp from this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) with my C++ Eclipse Editor following failures are shown:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type 'beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Request' could not be resolved    add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 4  Semantic Error
Type 'beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Response' could not be resolved   add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 5  Semantic Error
Field 'sum' could not be resolved   add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 7  Semantic Error
Field 'a' could not be resolved add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 7  Semantic Error
Field 'b' could not be resolved add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 7  Semantic Error
Field 'ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b)' could not be resolved   add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 8  Semantic Error
Field 'ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b)' could not be resolved   add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 8  Semantic Error
Field 'ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%ld]", (long int)res.sum)' could not be resolved   add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 9  Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, bool (#0::*)(#1 &, #2 &), #0 *)
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions &)
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, bool (#0::*)(ros::ServiceEvent<#1,#2> &), #0 *)
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, bool (#0::*)(#1 &, #2 &), const boost::shared_ptr<#0> &)
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, bool (#0::*)(ros::ServiceEvent<#1,#2> &), const boost::shared_ptr<#0> &)
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, bool (*)(#0 &, #1 &))
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, bool (*)(ros::ServiceEvent<#0,#1> &))
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, const boost::function<bool (#0 &, #1 &)> &, const boost::shared_ptr<const void> &)
ros::ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, const boost::function<bool (#0 &)> &, const boost::shared_ptr<const void> &)
'   add_two_ints_server.cpp /beginner_tutorials/src line 18 Semantic Error
```

What file or dependency is eclipse missing? Or are that failures with multiple origins?

edit: I followed this [IDE](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs)-Tutorial.

At step "1. Reusing your shell's environment", i build an new ros-package and copied the "c++ eclipse" files in it. Then I created a launch folder and file and pasted following:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="eclipse2" name="eclipse" type ="eclipse"/>
</launch>
```

By using the command "roslaunch eclipse2 eclipse.launch" I started C++ - Eclipse.
(Eclipse starts with some warnings of missing log-files)

But these failures are still there.

Also I follwed the other steps of the tutorial.

Any Suggestions?

Many Thanks in advance
Dominik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42657/erros-in-eclipse-c++-by-opening-file-from-ros-tutorial/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-30**:
Did you create the project with make eclipse-project?

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2012-09-03**:
Yes, i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please see the [IDEs Page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs) to use ROS code in Eclipse

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2